# Cannot restore the navigation drawer button after changing it with a back button

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

When I go back after changing it to a back button it disappears with the following code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
mToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

drawer.setDrawerListener(mToggle);
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

I think that code should make the navigation drawer button to open menu to appear again, but it doesn't.

Any idea of what could be wrong in that code, so the navigation drawer button appears again?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

if (getSupportActionBar() != null) getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

//.....
```

Also, you could use *androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI* package to setup your drawer menu.

[Here](https://proandroiddev.com/android-jetpack-navigationui-a7c9f17c510e) are good articles about NavigationUI.